# Stop .animate recalculating .scroll position

Tags: jquery

If you look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7bdkB/60/) when you pass the div id "one" and then scroll again before it has moved the full 190px the animation will stop while you are scrolling. I want the animation to keep moving to 190px even if you do scroll again and the same for when it goes back -100px.

```
var $test = $(".test2");
$(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > $('#one').position().top) {
$test.stop().animate({left: "190px"}, 1000);
} else {
$test.stop().animate({left: "-100px"}, 1000);
}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to have a variable that indicates the animation is running, and then reset it when the animation is done:

```
var $test2 = $(".test2");
var running = false;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if (running)
        return;
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        running = true;
        $test2.stop().animate({left: "200px"}, 
                              300,
                              function() {
                                  running = false;
                              }
                             );
    } else {
        running = true;
        $test2.stop().animate({left: "-90px"},
                              300,
                              function() {
                                  running = false;
                              }
                             );
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand the functionality that you are looking for, but if you want the animations to complete regardless of the fact that the user has scrolled up, you can just remove the `.stop()` from your event function.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VYwXH/)

**JS**

```
var $test = $(".test2");

$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > $('#one').position().top) {
    $test.animate({left: "190px"}, 1000);

  } else {
    $test.animate({left: "-100px"}, 1000);
  }

})
```